# How to install gnuplot 5.4 at ubuntu20.04

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade, add-apt-repository, gnuplot

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, I work with Gnuplot 5.2.8, but only some features are at the version most recent.

My question-specific question is. How to upgrade Gnuplot 5.4.0 at ubuntu 20.04?.

Thanks community

Comment: Thanks for your time @user68186, My question-specific question is. How to upgrade Gnuplot 5.4.0 at ubuntu 20.04?. I considered it appropriate to explain my situation about the problem. On the next occasion, I will keep in mind your observation. Thanks again

Comment: Download the Gnuplot 5.2.8 source (` http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/`), read the `README*` and `INSTALL` files, build it yourself. You may have to `sudo apt install build-essential` to get the compiler and tools. Tell the `configure` script to install `gnuplot` into the `/usr/local` hierarchy. A benefit of Free Open Source Software.

Comment: Thanks for your response @waltinator, I try to install this version but I have a problem. How do you set libcerf variables to install Gnuplot at Linux?. I install libcer1, but Gnuplot doesn't this package.

Comment: Why doesn't work `./configure --with-PACKAGE LIBCERF1=YES`, for install gnuplot5.4 with this option??

Comment: AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site.

Answer (score 3):

For gnuplot 5.4.1 with qt terminal:

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev qttools5-dev-tools

cd ~
wget https://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuplot/gnuplot/5.4.1/gnuplot-5.4.1.tar.gz
tar -xvzf gnuplot-5.4.1.tar.gz
cd gnuplot-5.4.1

./configure --with-qt=qt5
make -j # uses more jobs for faster compiling and linking
make check # make a test before installing
sudo make install # a better method would be to use checkinstall -> creates a deb

cd ~
rm -rf gnuplot-5.4.1*
```

Comment: To be clear, the following makes a deb:  `sudo checkinstall make install`

Comment: Thank you for the concise instructions.

Comment: I **STRONGLY** recommend **AGAINST** using `checkinstall`. It's too dangerous. It bricked my system – had to boot from a live boot USB and fix the root directory of the harddrive. See https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/x08ex6/psa_checkinstall_can_brick_your_ubuntu_2204_system/ and https://github.com/giuliomoro/checkinstall/issues/4